# Missing return statement in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, return

I have a `for` loop that returns values from an array.

```
public static String getPieces(){
        for(int y=0; y<=7; y++)
            for(int x=0; x<=7; x++)
                return piece[x][y];
}
```

There is a return statement clearly in the method that will return every time it is called. Why does it say `missing return statement`?

Comment: Compiler error apart, what's the point of those `for` loops?

Comment: I want it to return 64 values, 8 in the y direction, and 8 in the x direction.

Comment: You can only return one value from a function. Why not just have it return the array?

Comment: A method returns only once. If you want to return `64` values, then you perhaps need to create an array, and return an array of those 64 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the `loop` being completely pointless (because it will return piece[0][0]), adding an extra return line might help you:

```
public static String getPieces() {
    for (int y = 0; y <= 7; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 7; x++) {
            return piece[x][y];
        }
    }     
}
```

Since you stated that you want to return 64 values, you'll have to return an array.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPieces() {
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int y = 0; y <= 7; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 7; x++) {
            strings.add(piece[x][y]);
        }
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to import any classes for `ArrayList`?

Comment: @JoeBoyle: Because the reason you mention is nonsense. The size of the arrays doesn't matter. Think about it.

Comment: @Insederec Yeah, you'd need to import java.util.ArrayList

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux You're telling me that if you have two arrays of zero elements, and you try to iterate over them and return a value, it will go through them and reach the return statement? Not happening.

Comment: @JoeBoyle: Read the code again, he uses fixed `x <= 7`.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Well then. I apologize. I didn't recognize that.

Comment: I get `incompatible types
found   : java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
required: java.lang.String
  return strings;`

Comment: @Insederec Did you change the return type to ArrayList<String> as I did?

Comment: This worked, but I've discovered I need to rethink my code in order to get what I wanted to happen to work in the way I intended. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 3):

**[JLS §8.4.7. Method Body](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7)** says this:

> **If a method is declared to have a return type, then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally ([§14.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1)).**

Where the definition of *complete normally* is *not competing abruptly*. A `return` statement is something that completes *abruptly*.

Next, assuming this syntax for a `for` statement:

```
for ( ForInit_opt ; Expression_opt ; ForUpdate_opt ) Statement
```

The **[JLS §14.14.1.2. Iteration of for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.2)** states this :

> Next, a for iteration step is performed, as follows:
>
> - If the *Expression* is present, it is evaluated. If the result is of type `Boolean`, it is subject to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
>   - If evaluation of the *Expression* or the subsequent unboxing conversion (if any) **completes abruptly, the `for` statement completes abruptly for the same reason**.

So, the fact that the *Expression* might complete abruptly means that the for loop will complete abruptly as well, for the same reason, which is of course not "returning". So, the `return` statement might be unreachable.

However, we both know that it will be always reached. But that is a shortcoming of the compiler intelligence. If you remove the *Expressions* (they are optional), or replace them with `true`, the compiler doesn't complain. Your code is basically this:

```
// This snippet won't work as method body
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    return "Hello"; 
}
```

In comparison with this:

```
// This snippet compiles fine
for (int i = 0; true; ++i)
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

This means that there are two options:

- `i < 10` can complete abruptly
- the compiler can't determine wether `i <= 10` evaluates to true or not, even if you declared `int i = 0`.

I went searching through the JLS and didn't find anything about abrupt completion of a simple `i < 10` statement. So, I guess that the reason why this happens is actually the second one: he can't be sure that `i < 10` will evaluate to `true` for at least once.

---

So, in order to make the compiler shut up about the fact that he is not certain about the return statement actually being called, you can let the method complete *abruptly*  by yourself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    return "Hello"; 
}
throw new RuntimeException("Should never, ever, reach this point!");
```

Answer (score 1):

because return statement is under `for` block.

As you have mentioned return type is String and your method has to have return tye. But with your program compiler does not know in advance that flow does not go under for loop and no return is possible. So compiler is extra smart. Is n't it :)

Try

```
public static String getPieces(){
       String result = null;
        for(int y=0; y<=7; y++)
            for(int x=0; x<=7; x++)
                result= piece[x][y];

        return result;
}
```

it will work

Comment: You're returning an integer for a function with a String return type?