# Using methods to calculate account balance

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to return a bank balance that takes into account the number of years, the amount in the account and the interest rate. However, when I compile the program, I receive an error on the return statement. When I try putting the return outside the loop, i get another error.

In Loop:

```
Exercise3.java:35: error: missing return statement
```

Out of Loop:

```
Exercise3.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
}return sum;
        ^
symbol:   variable sum
location: class Exercise3
1 error
```

The code is below

```
import java.util.Scanner;//import scanner class


public class Exercise3{//Name of prograsm

    public static void main(String args[]){ //declare main method

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//Declare the scanner method

        System.out.println("How much in in your account?");//ask user for balance details 
        double accBalance = sc.nextDouble();//Store balance details

        System.out.println("how many years are you saving? "); //ask the user for how many years they will be saveing
        double yrSaving = sc.nextDouble();// Amount of years stored

        System.out.println("What is the yearly interest rate ?");//ask the user for the interest rate
        double rateInterest = sc.nextDouble();//store the interest rate

        double results = balanceAccount(accBalance, yrSaving, rateInterest);//invoke the methofd
        System.out.println(results); //print thte  results of the method 
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Calculate the balance of the account method

    public static double balanceAccount(double accBalance, double yrSaving, double rateInterest){

        double rate = rateInterest / 100;

        for(int x = 0; x <= yrSaving; x++){

            double sum = accBalance*rate;
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing return statement in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799367/missing-return-statement-in-for-loop)

Comment: I suggest that you step away from your computer and work some examples by hand. After you do so, explain to your Mom or roommate or some other person how to do the calculation. Now write the steps **in words** how you do this. Then compare your words to the code that you have here. Do the words match what your code does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a body for your method. Your problem was that you were not returning in every scenario. Also your `sum` logic was faulted.

```
 double rate = rateInterest / 100;
 double sum = 0;
 for(int x = 0; x <= yrSaving; x++){
   sum += accBalance * rate;
 }
 return sum;
```

Comment: This still does not correctly calculate the compound interest.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That's not required to answer his question, neither was it asked. That's a math problem, the question here is to fix the errors.

Comment: Yes it does. Thus my **comment** below the answer explaining the basic skills needed to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did it

public static double balanceAccount(double accBalance, double yrSaving, double rateInterest){

```
double rate = rateInterest / 100;
double sum = 0;
double finishAmt = 0;

    sum += accBalance * rate;

    finishAmt = sum * yrSaving +(accBalance);
    return finishAmt;
}
```

}